# 3rd Gen iPad photostream

Tags: icloud, photos

I just bought an iPad for my mother and now I would like to turn on Photostream so she can see them.

Is there a setting I can change to make this possible?

Comment: If you're looking for general information - you can't do better than the [FAQ Apple has prepared for the service](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486). Feel free to ask another more specific question or edit this one if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

In `Settings`, login to iCloud (under the `iCloud` tab) and there you will get the option for Photo stream.

You can also go to the `Photos` tab in `Settings` and enable Photostream there. If you haven't logged into your iCloud account yet, the switch either won't be there or will prompt for login information.

If you are talking about sharing Journals in iPhoto through iCloud, start by creating a Journal, then tap the Share icon in the upper right corner, tap `iCloud` and follow the prompts.